# Response to missing required Properties in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

Given the following controller:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] Model req)
        {
            return $"Your name is {req.Name}";
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

if I post an empty body `{}`, the response is:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Name": [
            "The Name field is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000002-0002-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I would like to change this response, so it becomes easier to automatically pass the error message on to the user. So I would like it to look more like this:

```
{
    "error": 999,
    "message": "Field 'name' is required."
}
```

I tried to extend the `RequiredAttribute`-class like so:

```cs
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} is required";
    }
}
```

which sadly only changes the returned string in the collection, like so

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Name": [
            "Name is required"
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000006-0000-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

Comment: The `[ApiController]` attribute makes ASP.NET Core use [problem details](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807), a standard for API failure results. If you don’t want that, you will have to modify the default API conventions.

Comment: Interestingly the error responses are NOT in accordance with the IETF specifications that you posted. They are maybe similar, but that's all ...

Comment: Why are they not in accordance?
"3.1. Members of a Problem Details Object" states "A problem details object CAN have the following members:". This clearly states that all attributes are optional.
"3.2. Extension Members" states that additional attributes can be added.

Answer (score 3):

When utilizing a controller with the ApiController attribute applied, ASP.NET Core automatically handles model validation errors by returning a 400 Bad Request with ModelState as the response body. It is related to [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses) . You could customize BadRequest response like below :

```
  services.AddMvc()
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                    {
                        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;
                        return new BadRequestObjectResult(FormatOutput(modelState));
                    };
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Customize the `FormatOutput` method to your whims.

```
public List<Base> FormatOutput(ModelStateDictionary input)
    {
        List<Base> baseResult = new List<Base>();
        foreach (var modelState in input.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                Base basedata = new Base();
                basedata.Error = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                basedata.Message =error.ErrorMessage; 
                baseResult.Add(basedata);
            }
        }
        return baseResult;
    }

public class Base
{
    public int Error { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and add this code below the [Requried] annotation

```
[StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Name length can't be less than 1 or greater than 150 characters.", MinimumLength = 1)]
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This does not throw an error if the property is missing as a whole and IF the length is out of bounce, this has the exact same response structure, that I am trying to replace ...

Comment: Seems like going against the grain, however, it still should be possible.  Have you looked at asp.net core middle ware? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: You are correct the request never even gets to the class, because routing to the method expects an object, for example route Post([FromBody] Model req) means http://localhost:45234/Values/Model (request) with a body object of Model. Therefore if model is not present the request must not be targeting the Values route.  Middleware allows you to see every request before they are handled.

Comment: Here you go, an example is halfway down the page, https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/