# How can I capture the validation errors of a model to return them in a json attribute under the name that I decide?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically in my model I have the `nombre` property which is `required` if the user does not send this property an error like this is returned:

```
{
 "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|17d12efe-4ec4106f4029b56b.",
"errors": {
    "Nombre": [
        "The Nombre field is required."
    ]
 }
}
```

I would like to get these errors to return in a json style to the client side:

```
{
 "ok": false,
 "error": "message": {.....errors } // (.errors)
}
```

this is my Api:

```
    //to make the validation errors of `required` appear I do not send anything
 
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] genre data)
    {
        context.Add(data);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response to missing required Properties in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233662/response-to-missing-required-properties-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a result class and return an instance of it from your Controller. eg.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Result> Post([FromBody] Data data)
{
    try 
    {
        context.Add(data);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new Result();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new Result() 
        { 
            Ok = false, 
            Errors = new [] 
            { 
                new ResultError() { Message = "An error message"} 
            } 
        }
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public bool Ok { get; set; } = true;
    public ResultError[] Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ResultError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like you should be able to examine the Exception to provide your error message.

A good implementation of the Result class and how to handle errors gracefully can be found here https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/

Comment: The way his model is set up, this code will never hit. He's using `[Required]` attribute. The framework is setup so that his endpoint will never get hit if validation fails. This won't work.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks @Andy, I thought it was the SaveChangesAsync that was throwing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233662/response-to-missing-required-properties-in-asp-net-core

Comment: That's what he's looking for. You could probably vote to close the question as duplicate and use that link as the redirect.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I'll do just that if I can find out where to do it :)

Comment: @Andy please feel free to do the honours :)

Comment: Thank you very much, but indeed this answer in this case will help me

Comment: I don't know how you found that answer so quickly. i was looking for like 25 minutes.

Comment: @Andy Haha, my google-fu is stronger than my [Required]-fu I guess

Comment: Guys, I'm pretty new to c #, do you know how I can return a json with a state code of 200? I know that I must specify that I want to return a json, but I don't know how to do it https://i.imgur.com/dYtPKGV.jpg

Comment: @yavg You can just return an object, like Result from the Controller in the answer I posted, or, you can use return new JsonResult(model) instead of  return new BadRequestObjectResult(...)